# SQL Multiple Many-to-many Self-referencing Associations (Sequelize.js)

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, database, database-design

just wondering if the following thing is the proper thing to do.

I have a `User` table, in which a user can be a buyer or a seller. I have a `Sale` table to record the item sold/purchased by a user.

Im currently planning to give `User` a starting schema that looks like this:

```
id
user_name
display_name
... (other attrs)
```

A `Sale` would have a starting schema like this:

```
id
product_id
price
... (other relevant attrs)
```

The part I'd like to ask about is the associations. There are two ways of doing it from what I see. We could either establish 2 many-to-many rules for buyer and sellers respectively, or to have `sale` belong to `User` twice once as buyer and once as seller. The end state is the same, but I'm not sure which way is better/recommended, and why.

Option 1 (using Sequelize.js format):

```
User.belongsToMany(User, {
    through: Sale,
    as: 'buyer',
    foreignKey: 'buyer_id',
}

User.belongsToMany(User, {
    through: Sale,
    as: 'seller',
    foreignKey: 'seller_id',
}
```

Option 2:

```
Sale.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'seller_id',
}

Sale.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'buyer_id',
}
```

In the end, both options result in the foreign key columns `buyer_id` and `seller_id` added to the `Sale` model. But which approach would you recommend? And why?

Comment: A sale has-a buyer and a seller. A user has many sales (either as buyer or seller). Does a sale ever have more than one buyer and seller pairing? Unless you can sell one TV to two people, i'm not seeing a M:M relationship here

Comment: @CaiusJard I'd picture the M:N association differently here. A seller can make a sale to multiple buyers, and multiple sellers can make sales to the same buyer. It's just each sale being differentiated by a `sale_id`. Correct me if im wrong

Comment: To me a sale is a pairing of a buyer and seller and some item possibly multiples of an item in which case it's an order with multiple items. Think about eBay: You have one TV, how do you sell it to multiple people? You can't. How can you buy 10 TVs and end up with one sale in your history? You can't. The rule (I propose because it maps to real life) is that a transaction has a buyer and a seller and one or more items, but you don't have one transaction featuring multiple buyers or sellers if you're transferring multiple items, you have multiple items in the order (not multiple people)

Comment: If you buy a TV every month from the same person you have, at the end of the year, 12 sales all with the same one buyer and one seller, you don't have one sale with you and the seller in 12 times each

Answer (score 0):

`Sale` is the association table that implements among other things the many-to-many relation between sellers and buyers.

```
id
product_id
price
seller_id
buyer_id
... (other attrs)
```

Note that `Sale` table is usually used in OLAP, hence it is slightly denormalized.
In OLTP you have usually document or event tables which contains seller and buyer IDs in the headers. I.e.

```
orders
----
id
date
seller_id
buyer_id
...

order_items
----
order_id
item_index
product_id
price
qty
....
```